# How to configure SQL Server in Visual Studio 2013 to allow remote connection

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf

I am using Visual Studio 2013. I am trying to create a WCF service. In this service I have a database. When I run this service it returns data. But when I am trying from client application I get an exception. I am using default Visual Studio 2013 SQL Server. Can anyone please help me? What is the problem and how can I solve it?

Error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred.
>   Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event
>   log for error details. )
>   Server stack trace:
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message
>   reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version,
>   FaultConverter faultConverter)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:
>   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)
>   at WindowsApplication1.ServiceReference1.IService1.login(String id,
>   String password)
>   at WindowsApplication1.ServiceReference1.Service1Client.login(String id,
>   String password) in e:\study\7thsemister\Paint app\Paint app\Service
>   References\ServiceReference1\Reference.cs:line 77
>   at WindowsApplication1.login.login_btn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>   in e:\study\7thsemister\Paint app\Paint app\login.cs:line 26

Comment: Can you provide as much information as possible around the connection string and each context where it works or does not work?

Comment: It looks like there is an error occuring in LocalDB.  Have you followed this advice from the stack trace `50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details.` (i.e. have you looked in the Event Log)?

Comment: i am trying to authenticate username and password. when i give manually input from server side it give me fine results .but when i try from client application .it give me this huge exception

Comment: dear martin_costello i dnt have idea about it .can u please brief me little more about it . actually i am new to wcf

Comment: Given that you're new to WCF, may I recommend that you get some simple WCF services, without any database access, working first? And also learn to write SQL Server database client code, without involving anything fancy like WCF? Right now you're trying to do *two* things at the same time, both of which are immensely complex, and both of which are new to you. Pick one part of the problem to solve first.

Comment: Yes, getting a connection going to SQL Server can in itself be very challenging to a beginner, everything from Server configuration, firewall, authentication configuration, client configuration, client connection string, can interfere. See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2008/04/30/steps-to-troubleshoot-connectivity-issues.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all check you firewall setting.
if your problem still exist, check client proxy setting. 
also check you sql server connection from client. for do this create a new text file and change filename.txt to filename.udl, now run it and check your connection.

if your problem does not solve, provide your code.

Answer (score 1):

If the code accessing the database is on a different machine from the SQL Server database itself, you may need to enable remote connections on the database, or modify the the SQL Server Network Configuration to allow a network protocol. To enable remote connections, open the properties of your database server from SQL Server Management Studio (on the database server) and select "Allow remote connections to this server". To enable a network protocol, open the "SQL Server Network Configuration" application and enable a protocol such as "TCP/IP".

Here's an article with detailed instructions: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx